# map [] operand doesn't work c++

Tags: c++, c++11

hi my code looks something like this

```
class State
{
public:
    State * create(void);
};

typedef State * (*createFunc)(void);
class Registery
{
private:
   static std::map<std::string, createFunc> registery()
public:
   static void register_func(std::string key, createFunc func)
   {
       registery[key] = func;
   }
   static State * create(std::string key)
   {
       return registery[key]();
   }
};

int main()
{
   Registery::register_func("state", State::create);
   State * s = Registery::create("state");
}
```

the problem is that when I try to compile it I receive this error:

> error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are
>   ‘std::map< std::basic_string< char>, State* (*)()>()’ and ‘std::string
>   {aka std::basic_string< char>}’)

as far as I can see the types match so I don't really understand why I have an error

EDIT:
I fixed this line `static std::map<std::string, createFunc> registery()` to `static std::map<std::string, createFunc> registery;`
but know I get another error:

> undefined reference to `StateRegistry::registry'

Comment: You meant to write `static std::map<std::string, createFunc> registery;`.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. The question is as clear as an OP confused by the error message could make it, and if every question on SO had as clear and precise an example as this, I'd be more than happy. I would love to give it more than one +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   static std::map<std::string, createFunc> registery()
```

That is a declaration of a function, although the semicolon is missing and I am not sure why the compiler let’s you do this.

The error message is also telling you that the types in fact do not match:

> std::map< std::basic_string< char>, State* (*)()>()

The last `()` indicate that the type describes a callable taking no arguments.

You need to remove the `()` from your `registery` declaration and add a `;` instead.

Comment: I remove the () and added ; instead but nowI receive a linker error: undefined reference to `Registery::registery'

Comment: @CforLinux that's because you've only declared the static member. You need to define it as well.

Comment: @user2079303 as in creating an instance? Is there a way to create a class variable that doesn't require an instance?

Comment: All class data members, by definition, are instances of some type.   If you declare them as `static`, they need to be separately defined.   If not static, then each instance of the class contains an instance of each of its members - the members are initialised during construction of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Your static '**registery**' is only declared but not defined. To solve this you can append '**= {}**' to the declaration to make it a definition as well, or you add a definition statement like '**std::map<std::string, createFunc> Registery::registery;**' to your code.